# How to get back the repetitive fields value when come back to the browser after the form submission?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, dynamic

I have a form.

```
<form method="post" action="/action.php/" name="HTML Form">
    <input type="text" name="sudentname[]" required="required" />
    <div class="add_another_st">
    </div>
    <button class="btn add_another_st_btn" >Add Another Student</button>
    <!-- To add another field --> 
    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="confirm"><i class="fa fa-share-square-o">
        </i>&nbsp;Pay</button>
    <script>
        jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
            var wrapper = jQuery(".add_another_st");
            //Fields wrapper section 3
            var add_button  = jQuery(".add_another_st_btn");
            //Add button section 3
            var add_sec_3 = '<input type="text" name="sudentname[]" required="required" />';
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

So when I click on the button 'Add Another Student' this appends another student to the wrapper with the field name "sudentname[]"

**action.php**

```
<?php
$sudentname = $_POST['sudentname'];
if (isset($_POST['submitconfirm'])){ 
    // inserting into db - and this step works fine
}
?>
<form method="POST" name="form for action and to insert into db">
    <?php
$studentNo = '1';
foreach($sudentname as $key => $v){ ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    No
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?= $studentNo++ ?></td>
            <td>
                <?= $v.'<br/>'; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="sudentname[]" value="<?= $v ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php } // closing php tag ?>
    <button  onclick="history.go(-1);" type="submit" name="edit">EDIT</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submitconfirm"> CONFIRM </button>
</form>
```

this one works fine and inserting all the  student to the db if I click CONFIRM.
what I am trying to do is update/edit the fields values if the values are filled with some mistakes in HTML Form

When I click on the button edit it goes back to the form HTML Form but it shows only one field/student (and it's value) which were not poupulated by jQuery.

What I need is all the populated/appended fields with filled up details to edit/update.

How can I make them stay when I come from form for action and to insert into db to HTML Form?